# Recording Video Using AVCaptureVideoDataOutput at Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, video-recording

After fair amount of time we spend over the issue without result, I decided to ask it here.

We are using `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` to get pixel data of live video of the camera and using in `captureOutput` function. But we also want to record video using that data. Besides, we wonder if this video recording would have been compressed as much as the recorded video which is made with `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`.

I would like to inform you that using `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` we made recording without problem. But `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` and `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` is not working at the same time.

You can find out  our `captureOutput` function below;

```
    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

    let baseAddress             = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0)
    let bytesPerRow             = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer)
        videoWidth              = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer)
        videoHeight             = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer)
    let colorSpace              = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

    var bitmapInfo  = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)

    let context = CGContext(data: baseAddress, width: videoWidth, height: videoHeight, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)

    let imageRef = context!.makeImage()

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

    let data = imageRef!.dataProvider!.data as! NSData
    let pixels = data.bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)


   /* Because what we are doing with pixel data irrelevant  to the question we omitted the rest of the code to make it simple */




}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending some part of life I found how to record video when I am getting pixel information to make some basic  analysis on live video.

First I am setting the AVAssetWriter and call that function before giving actual record order.

```
var sampleBufferGlobal : CMSampleBuffer?
let writerFileName = "tempVideoAsset.mov"
var presentationTime : CMTime!
var outputSettings   = [String: Any]()
var videoWriterInput: AVAssetWriterInput!
var assetWriter: AVAssetWriter!


 func setupAssetWriter () {

    eraseFile(fileToErase: writerFileName)

    presentationTime  = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBufferGlobal!)

    outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey   : AVVideoCodecH264,
                      AVVideoWidthKey   : NSNumber(value: Float(videoWidth)),
                      AVVideoHeightKey  : NSNumber(value: Float(videoHeight))] as [String : Any]

    videoWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, outputSettings: outputSettings)


    assetWriter = try? AVAssetWriter(outputURL: createFileURL(writerFileName), fileType: AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie) 

    assetWriter.add(videoWriterInput)

}
```

I wrote an other function to make recording and called that function in captureOutput function to make recording after I copied sampleBuffer to sampleBufferGlobal, sampleBufferGlobal = sampleBuffer, in the same function.

```
func writeVideoFromData() {

    if assetWriter?.status == AVAssetWriterStatus.unknown {

        if (( assetWriter?.startWriting ) != nil) {

            assetWriter?.startWriting()
            assetWriter?.startSession(atSourceTime:  presentationTime)

        }   
    }   



      if assetWriter?.status == AVAssetWriterStatus.writing {   

            if (videoWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData == true) {


                if  videoWriterInput.append(sampleBufferGlobal!) == false {

                    print(" we have a problem writing video")

                }   
            }  
        }        
   }
```

Then to stop recording I used following function.

```
   func stopAssetWriter() {

    videoWriterInput.markAsFinished()

    assetWriter?.finishWriting(completionHandler: {


        if (self.assetWriter?.status == AVAssetWriterStatus.failed) {

            print("creating movie file is failed ")

        } else {

            print(" creating movie file was a success ")

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in




            })

        }

    })

}
```

Comment: do u have this full code in github or some blogpost?